# Liferay gives a StackOverFlow error when trying to access the homepage

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to start Liferay. It was working a few weeks ago. When I enter localhost:8080 I get a 404 error.

Here is the stack trace, where the error occurs. Does anyone have any ideas regarding how to fix this. I am using Liferay Portal 5.2.2 and Tomcat 5.5

```
08:07:46,919 ERROR [ContextLoader:220] Context initialization failed
java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(ClassLoader.java:891) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:301) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251) at 
java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(URL.java:1141) at java.net.URL.(URL.java:572) at 
java.net.URL.(URL.java:464) at 
sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:883) at 
sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:872) at 
sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:142) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:359) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:977) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:972) at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassL oader.java:1123) at 
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locateFromClasspa 
th(ConfigurationUtils.java:531) at 
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(Configurat ionUtils.java:513) at 
org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(Abstr actFileConfiguration.java:211) at
```

Comment: Nice, a stackoverflow question belonging to serverfault ;-) (couldn't resist)

Answer (score 2):

This forum thread on liferay.com could contain a hint hwo to solve this issue:

http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2436518

> I removed my portal-ext.properties and
>   changed my DB setting directly in
>   portal-impl.jar and now I am no longer
>   seeing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It might be [this issue](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-3329), fixed in the current trunk. The subversion commit information is also included in Jira, so you can apply the same patch to your code. (see the [fisheye](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-3329?page=com.atlassian.jira.ext.fisheye%3Afisheye-issuepanel) information in the issuetracker)

Otherwise (and if splattne's link didn't help) we'll need more information:

- What database is involved?
- Is this exception upon server start or on access to localhost:8080 ?
- What happens if you use a fresh installation (with your customizations, most likely in liferay's portal-ext.properties, also with the required database driver)
- Can you give more stacktrace information? I expect it to be prohibitively long, but a bit more information for localizing the root cause would be good.
- Did you try the [Liferay forums](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums)? There might be more people hanging around there with in-depth Liferay knowledge than here (no pun intended).